# No viable conversion from 'bool' to 'std::string'

Tags: c++

I have some code that looks like this:

```
static std::string Foo(const std::string& blah)
{
   if ( someWierdEdgeCase() ){
      return false;  // <-- this line has a compiler error
   }

   std::string resourcePath;
   resourcePath.append("/assets/");
   return resourcePath; 
}
```

It used to compile fine, but then I upgraded to Xcode 5.1, and now it no longer compiles.  The error I get is the following one:
No viable conversion from 'bool' to 'std::string'

I would like to know what I should replace 'return false' with so that this works the way it used to.

Normally, I would be happy to return something other than false, and clearly that is not good behavior. But somehow this code used to compile and run, and I want to understand what it was doing, in case some other part of this codebase is relying on what is certainly weird behavior.

Comment: You can throw an exception.

Comment: Your return type is `std::string`. When you `return false`, it is a different type. What happens if you just `return "";` ?

Comment: The function returns string, so you've got to return a string. I'd say either return an empty string to indicate an error (and be sure all callers are prepared to deal with that), throw an exception, or redefine the func to return a different type.

Comment: You can also use `boost::optional`.

Comment: What's unclear about this compiler error message please? There aren't any automatic conversions from `bool` to `std::string`, period.

Comment: `It used to compile fine`  no, it didn't :)

Comment: It is an interesting question why this used to compile. Perhaps an earlier version of Xcode would allow an implicit conversion from "false" to a null char*?

Comment: You could return `std::string("false")`, added `std::string` for emphasis.

Comment: @dlf: At least in MSVC, you can't construct a `std::string` from a null `char*`.  I don't know if XCode allowed it or not though

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
  return false;  // <-- this line has a compiler error
```

There is no standard way to convert bool to std::string (please correct me if there is or was something special in gcc (the old XCode mac compiler)). This means that your code base used to contain explicit code to convert the bool to string.

If it is not compiling now this suggests this conversion was removed from your code base.

A couple of people of suggested alternatives. But I doubt any of these are going to work. As the old code had a depedency on how it used to work. So making any specific recomendation will depend on working out how the old code compiled and what it returned when `someWierdEdgeCase()` is true. Basically you need to replicate this behavior.

Otherwise you need to hunt down all used cases in your code and change the behavior to match the new behavior. In this case I would change the name of the function. Re-Compile and see where the code breaks and check the behavior at each location and make sure it behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
static std::string Foo(const std::string& blah)
{
   std::string resourcePath = "";
   if ( someWierdEdgeCase() ){
      return resourcePath; // <-- Now you're returning a string
   }

   resourcePath.append("/assets/");
   return resourcePath; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the return type to be - for whatever reason - not always present, return by **pointer**, instead of returning by value.

```
static yourType* Foo(const std::string& blah){
   if ( someWierdEdgeCase() ){
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Then you can test and assign the function in the same line

```
yourType* result;
if(result = Foo("something")){
  // the result was correct
```

Of course - since your function returns a `std::string`, you can return an empty string (`""`), or - also independent of the return type - throw an exception.

Comment: The *returning raw pointer* solution opens up another can of worms involving ownership issues. The only sane solutions in this case are to return an empty string, or throw an exception.

Comment: @Praetorian if you're worried about ownership issues, there're still shared and unique pointers. Also - the pointer itself can be a member of a class, which can handle the memory when needed.

Comment: @Praetorian: or `optional`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue that with the fact that my interface file and implementation file were using different data types in method declaration.Putting same data type on both place in method declaration error went away.