# Return False or Value C++

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I have an avl tree that houses objects that contain a string identifier.

I am having a user input a string and then I want to parse the tree to see if that user string matches any of the objects in the tree identifier.  If there are no objects that have an identifier that matches the user's string, i want to create a object with the identifer set as the user's string.  If the object with an identifier does match the user's input, I want to return the object to the user.   At the moment I have two functions, one that returns a bool if the object exists in the tree already and one that returns the object to the console if it already exists in the tree.  Is there a way to combine these two steps into one function?  I am looking for something like:

```
if(...) // the item exists in the tree
{
    //return the object
}
else
{
    avltreeObject.insert(user_string);
}
```

Comment: Why not return the newly inserted object in the `else` case? If you need to also return a status (found or inserted) either have a boolean return value and use a passed object reference argument and set that, or you can return a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) with the status as `first` and the object as `second`.

Comment: Usually the retrieval function returns null if the object does not exist, and so you could call this and distinguish further processing according to that.

Comment: You might follow the std::map implementation

Comment: Why do I feel the question is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417592/no-viable-conversion-from-bool-to-stdstring

Comment: In this case here I'd also return the newly inserted value. In cases where I need a  "null" value for value classes, I normally use Boost.Optional: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the return type `std::pair<bool, Object>`.

```
if(/*the item exists in the tree*/)
{
   return std::make_pair(false, object);
}
else
{
   avltreeObject.insert(user_string);
   return std::make_pair(true, object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Object obj = avltreeObject.retrieve(user_string);
if( object != 0 ){
    return obj;
} else {
    avltreeObject.insert(user_string);
    return avltreeObject.retrieve(user_string);
}
```

The `insert` function might return the newly created object, so this can be improved.